# Forgotten Travels

Tags: pattern, geography

I normally like to go on travelling holidays, where I visit several different places.

Last year I went to:

> Chad
>   Angola
>   Malawi
>   Eritrea

This year I pushed the boat out and went to even more places:

> Wyoming
>   New Mexico
>   Colorado
>   Minnesota
>   Nebraska
>   Arkansas

Unfortunately I've now run out of money so can only go to one place next year,
 but I've been planning it all along.

Can you tell me where I'm going next year?

Comment: Is Eritrea spelled wrong on purpose?

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu nope, I'm just a dumb, changed now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your planning on going to:

> **The United Kingdom or UK**
>  
>  If you follow in order the listed places of each trip separately. The first trip will take you in a "U" shape geographically. The second list will take you through the U.S. roughly in a "K" pattern. Put them both together and you get the name of your next destination - The U.K.

Comment: Could you please explain why? I am curious how you get to this.

Comment: Just added the explanation. Sorry, I usually throw an answer in and add a description after ;)

Comment: Oh I see, nice job, you got the tick!

Comment: Hot damn. I was hoping it would take a little longer for someone to try this. Then again, whenever there is a geography question, this is the first thing I try :D

Comment: Fun puzzle! Interesting how those destinations in Africa make a pretty perfect rectangle. Possibly a basis for another puzzle in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> The acrostic of the first four places is CAME. Any meaning?

Comment: Nope, just a happy coincidence